# How to export a SharePoint List to Excel using PnP Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

How can I export a SharePoint List to Excel using PnP Powershell. I have spend hours googling it. But no luck. I found this code below but i think it isn't PnP Powershell code.

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity http://content.contoso.cloud -ItemUrl /lists/testlist -Path "c:\export\export1.cmp"
```

Does someone knows the exact code?

P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PnP PowerShell not provide function to export list item to Excel directly.
You could use the code below to achieve, using Export-CSV command:

## Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
  
##Variables for Processing
$SiteUrl = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/"
$ListName="xxx"
$ExportFile ="c:\Scripts\ListRpt.csv"
$UserName="xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password ="xxx"
 
#Setup Credentials to connect
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,(ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force))
 
#Set up the context
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
$Context.Credentials = $credentials
  
#Get the List
$List = $Context.web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)
 
#Get All List Items
$Query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$ListItems = $List.GetItems($Query)
$context.Load($ListItems)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
 
#Array to Hold List Items
$ListItemCollection = @()
 
#Fetch each list item value to export to excel
 $ListItems |  foreach {
    $ExportItem = New-Object PSObject
    $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Title" -value $_["Title"]
   
    #Add the object with above properties to the Array
    $ListItemCollection += $ExportItem
 }
#Export the result Array to CSV file
$ListItemCollection | Export-CSV $ExportFile -NoTypeInformation
 
Write-host "List data Exported to CSV file successfully!"
```

Reference:

[SharePoint Online: Export List Items to CSV using PowerShell](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/03/export-list-items-to-csv-in-sharepoint-online-using-powershell.html)